# Email Alert on VPN connection

Tags: openvpn, raspberrypi

I was hoping that someone had an idea about how to get it so that whenever someone establishes a VPN connection into my network I get an email about it.

Could I do this by having a script running and checking openvpn logs? I used the pivpn script to set up the openvpn server.  So could it be done by checking the pivpn -c option?

I imagine I could do it with an if than statement on the openvpn logs but how would I get it to only show new connections?

Answer (score 3):

The OpenVPN command has `--client-connect` and `--client-disconnect` options that allow you to run scripts for those (and other) events.

You can then create a script that emails you with information about the connection.

OpenVPN will provide a number of environment variables when executing these scripts, allowing you to attach connection information to those e-mails.

In my configuration, I have the following lines in /etc/openvpn/server.conf:

```
script-security 2
client-connect /etc/openvpn/server/connect-disconnect.sh
client-disconnect /etc/openvpn/server/connect-disconnect.sh
```

My `/etc/openvpn/server/connect-disconnect.sh` is owned by `nobody` (as this is the user that my system executes OpenVPN as) and contains the following (warning! long and ugly shell script incoming!):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Connect/disconnect script for OpenVPN clients
# For all available variables, see the "Environmental Variables" section
# at https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/

from_address="openvpn@$HOSTNAME"
from_name="openvpn@$HOSTNAME"
to_address="my-email-address"

function unitify_bytes {
        bytes=$1
        if [ "$bytes" -gt "1073741824" ]; then
                echo $(( $bytes / 1073741824 )) GiB
        elif [ "$bytes" -gt "1048576" ]; then
                echo $(( $bytes / 1048576 )) MiB
        elif [ "$bytes" -gt "1024" ]; then
                echo $(( $bytes / 1024 )) KiB
        else
                echo $bytes B
        fi
}

function unitify_seconds {
        local SS=$1

        if [ "$SS" -ge "60" ]; then
                local MM=$(($SS / 60))
                local SS=$(($SS - 60 * $MM))

                if [ "$MM" -ge "60" ]; then
                        local HH=$(($MM / 60))
                        local MM=$(($MM - 60 * $HH))

                        if [ "$HH" -ge "24" ]; then
                                local DD=$(($HH / 24))
                                local HH=$(($HH - 24 * $DD))
                                local time_string="$DD days, $HH hours, $MM minutes and $SS seconds"
                        else
                                local time_string="$HH hours, $MM minutes and $SS seconds"
                        fi
                else
                        local time_string="$MM minutes and $SS seconds"
                fi

        else
                local time_string="$SS seconds"
        fi

        echo "$time_string"
}


if [ "$script_type" == "client-connect" ]; then
        action="connected to"
else
        action="disconnected from"
        action_specific_info=" \
<dt>Session Duration</dt> <dd>$(unitify_seconds $time_duration)</dd> \
<dt>Received</dt> <dd>$(unitify_bytes $bytes_received)</dd> \
<dt>Sent</dt> <dd>$(unitify_bytes $bytes_sent)</dd> \
"

fi

now=$(echo $(date +"%c"))

cat <<EOF | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f "$from_address" $to_address
Subject: OpenVPN: $common_name $action $HOSTNAME
Content-Type: text/html
From: $from_name<$from_address>
Date: `date -R`

<html>
<head>
<style>
dt {
        float: left;
        width: 30%;
        text-align: right;
        padding: .25em;
        clear: left;
        font-weight: bold;
}
dd {
        float: left;
        width: 60%;
        padding: .25em 0;
}
dl:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Client <i>$common_name</i> has $action OpenVPN</h1>

<h2>Connection Details</h2>

<dl>
<dt>Client Common Name</dt> <dd>$common_name</dd>
<dt>Connection Start</dt> <dd>$time_ascii</dd>
<dt>Client WAN IP</dt> <dd>$untrusted_ip</dd>
<dt>Client LAN IP</dt> <dd>$ifconfig_pool_remote_ip</dd>
${action_specific_info}
</dl>

<hr/>
<p>OpenVPN at $HOSTNAME.</p>
</body>
</html>
EOF
```

Note that you should update the variables at the top to match your environment. I have `sendmail` configured to forward all mail to my mail account, so you might need more configuration/script changes n that area...

Answer (score 0):

You can tail -f the log file so you only see most recent additions to a script that emails when new matches your criteria

Possible code to use.

- This code uses mutt to send the email.
- set your logfile to watch in the variable: logfile
- set your email address in the variable: emailaddress
- There is a hard coded forever while loop.
- The tail -f follows as lines are added to the file and the -c 0 tells tail to only look for the last 0 bytes when it restarts so that it doesn't re-read the last 10 lines and send you extra old alerts.

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  words_to_match="Connection established"
  logfile=~/test.log
  emailaddress="youremailaddress@company.com"

  tail -f -c 0  ${logfile} | (while true ; do
      read -r line_to_check
      echo ${line_to_check} | grep -q ${words_to_match}
      if [ "$?" = "0" ] ; then
        echo "${line_to_check}" | mutt -s "VPN Login" ${emailaddress}
      fi
    done
  )
  ```

Comment: That's a good idea. My batch scripting is a bit dated. Do you have any ideas on how to build that script? Mainly how to make it look for "Connection established".  I was thinking something along the lines of

if [[ tail -f == *"Connection Established"* ]]; then
  mail -s "VPN connection established" root@localhost
fi

Any thoughts?

Comment: did the code work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this script wirted on python3:
https://github.com/fernandocastrovilar/openvpn_connection_notifier

It use the native OpenVPN status to retrieve users connected in last 5 minutes and notify them via email.